# Sliding window means with dplyr & zoo

Tags: r, mean, dplyr, zoo, sliding-window

I have a data frame containing per-base coverage along a genome. A much smaller example version is below:

```
> head(per_base_cov)
   contig_id position coverage
1   contig_1        1       40
2   contig_1        2       33
3   contig_1        3       40
4   contig_1        4       32
5   contig_1        5       36
6   contig_1        6       30
7   contig_1        7       40
8   contig_1        8       38
9   contig_1        9       36
10  contig_1       10       40
11  contig_2       11       38
12  contig_2       12       39
13  contig_2       13       34
14  contig_2       14       39
15  contig_2       15       39
16  contig_2       16       32
17  contig_2       17       30
18  contig_2       18       37
19  contig_2       19       33
20  contig_2       20       35
```

I would like to calculate sliding window means for each contig, every 4 positions and overlapping by 2 positions. I've tried the following using dplyr and zoo:

```
per_base_cov %>%
  group_by(contig_id) %>%
  mutate(cov.win.mean=rollapply(coverage,4,mean,by=2))
```

But I get the error message:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `cov.win.mean`.
x Input `cov.win.mean` can't be recycled to size 10.
ℹ Input `cov.win.mean` is `rollapply(coverage, 4, mean, by = 2)`.
ℹ Input `cov.win.mean` must be size 10 or 1, not 4.
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: contig_id = "contig_1".
```

Does anyone know how I could solve this? I would like an output that looks something like the following:

```
   contig_id mean_coverage
1   contig_1 36.25
2   contig_1 34.50
3   contig_1 36.00
4   contig_1 38.50
5   contig_2 37.5
6   contig_2 36
7   contig_2 34.5
8   contig_2 33.75
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. default output of `rollapply` is shorter than the input vector. Check `length(rollapply(1:10, 3, mean))` That is why you get the error. 2. You can use `rollapplyr(1:10, 3, mean, fill = NA)` or shorter `rollmeanr(1:10, 3, fill = NA)`. 3. What do you mean by 2000 step? 4. Can you provide a reproducible example with say 20 rows of data and show output for it?

Comment: Hi, sorry if my original post wasn't clear. I've updated it above and made it reproducible.

Comment: Update: I used ```per_base_cov %>%
  group_by(contig_id) %>%
  mutate(cov.win.mean=rollapply(coverage,4,mean,by=2, fill=NA))``` and this appears to have given me what I was looking for. Many thanks!

Comment: That's good to hear. I have never used `by` argument in `rollapply`. You can add that as an answer below. It might be helpful for people visiting this post in future. You can answer your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution with the help of Ronak below:

```
win_means <- per_base_cov %>%
  group_by(contig_id) %>%
  mutate(cov.win.mean=rollapply(coverage,4,mean,by=2, fill=NA))

win_means_complete <- win_means[complete.cases(win_means), ]
win_means_final <- win_means_complete[,c(1,2,4)]
win_means_final <- as.data.frame(win_means_final)

head(win_means_final)

  contig_id position cov.win.mean
1 contig_1   2        36.25
2 contig_1   4        34.50
3 contig_1   6        36.00
4 contig_1   8        38.50
5 contig_2  12        37.50
6 contig_2  14        36.00
```